# Linux camera defaults to /dev/video10?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, odroid

I am trying to connect to a camera on an Odroid U3 in XUbuntu 13.10 through OpenCV, but the webcam I am trying to use defaults to /dev/video10.  To the extent of my knowledge, OpenCV can only read up to /dev/video7.  How can I change the cameras device node?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to move one of the device node between 0-7 to some other unused node. And then link node0 to node10. This can be done through the terminal with root privilege.

example:

```
mv /dev/video0 /dev/videoX
ln /dev/video10 /dev/video0
```